# Correlation coefficient calculation

Tags: self-study, correlation, expected-value

Suppose an experiment having $r$ possible outcomes $1,2,\dots,r$ that occur with probabilities $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_r$ is repeated $n$ times independently.   Let $X$ be the number of times the first outcome occurs and $Y$ be the number of times the second outcome occurs.  Show that
$$
\mathbf{\rho}(X,Y)=-\sqrt{\dfrac{p_1p_2}{(1-p_1)(1-p_2)}}
$$
Here $\rho$ denotes the correlation coefficient.

My try :

Now I tried to do this by writing $X$ and $Y$ as sums of indicator functions.  Let $X=\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n}I_k$ and $Y=\displaystyle \sum_{s=1}^{n}J_s$. where $I_k=1$ if $i^{\text{th}}$ trial yields outcome one and $0$ otherwise.  Similarly define $J_s=1$ if the $s^{\text{th}}$ trial yields outcome two and $0$ otherwise. Now what I have found :
\begin{align}
&\mathbf{E}(X)=np_1,\mathbf{E}(Y)=np_2;\\
&\mathbf{E}(XY)=\sum_{s=1}^{n}\mathbf{E}(I_sJ_s)=np_1p_2;
\end{align}
So we have $\mathbf{Cov}(X,Y)=\mathbf{E}(XY)-\mathbf{E}(X)\mathbf{E}(Y)=-n(n-1)p_1p_2.$
But I need to find $\mathbf{Var}(X),\mathbf{Var}(Y)$ and thus $\mathbf{E}(X^2)$ and $\mathbf{E}(Y^2)$.  But I am having trouble finding these two expectations.  How to proceed?  Can someone help me?

Comment: Hint: $I_sJ_s=0$ since both $I_s$ and $J_s$ cannot have value 1 for any choice of $s$.